# Share a unique version of google colab doc?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Does anyone know how exactly I can share a unique version of a google colab doc? I have a colab sheet on my Google Drive and I want to allow for someone to access the file, run, make edits, etc. However, I don't want any of the edits made to be on *my version* of the doc.

I've searched everywhere...

Answer (score 1):

To share a link to your notebook that allows editing but does not modify your copy, first open the notebook in playground mode using the command palette. (Tools menu -> Command palette)

Then, select the 'Open in playground' command.

[image]

This will reload the notebook with a new URL that you can share, allowing others to modify and execute an ephemeral copy of the notebook without modifying the original. If they attempt to save, they will be prompted to create a copy in their own Drive.